# Multidimensional indexing in numpy array

Tags: numpy, numpy-ndarray

Let's suppose I have an image such that

```
image.shape=(280,280,3)
```

If I do `img[[[1,2],[1,2],[1,2]]].shape`, I obtain `(2,)`. But I expect to obtain `(2,2,2)`...

How can slicing be performed simultaneously on several dimensions in numpy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the [Array of Indices](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#index-arrays) syntax, when you probably want slices.

Try something like this:

```python
img[1:3, 1:3, 1:3]
```

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted. Thank you very much.